# Cannot read property 'unshift' of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, undefined

I don't know where are the issue I tried to push a new book to my books array and I get this error.[image]

This is the **book-edit.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authorsService.authorsChanged.subscribe(
      (authors: Author[]) => {
        this.authors = authors;
      }
    );
    this.authorsService.getAuthors();

    this.bookForm = new FormGroup({
      'id': new FormControl(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000)),
      'title': new FormControl('new book'),
      'author': new FormControl(null),
      'description': new FormControl('description'),
      'publishYear': new FormControl('1991'),
      'image': new FormControl('https://www.reduceimages.com/img/image-after.jpg')
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const book = {
      id: this.bookForm.value.id,
      title: this.bookForm.value.title,
      author: this.bookForm.value.author,
      description: this.bookForm.value.description,
      publishYear: this.bookForm.value.publishYear,
      image: this.bookForm.value.image
    };
    this.booksService.addBook(book);
    console.log(book);
  }
```

and this is the function I call from the **booksService.ts**

```
addBook(book: Book) {
    this.books.unshift(book);
    this.booksChanged.next(this.books);
  }
```

Comment: What's the full service code? Seems like `books` in the service was never initialised.

Comment: Looks like `books` in your booksService is not initialized. Do this: `books = [];` in your BookService.

Answer (score 2):

For the error log, it seems that `this.books` is not initialized. Can you initialize `books` variable in bookservice.ts to empty array like `books = []`

```
addBook(book: Book) {
    this.books.unshift(book);
    this.booksChanged.next(this.books);
  }
```